# How to cycle showing a set of divs like twitter badge widgets?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, widget, feed

Twitter has a widget that allows you to show status updates, cycling through a set of them to make it feel like real time updates.

I would like to do the same.  I'm using ruby on rails and would like to use a jquery script.

What I have are a set of 10 divs, rendered on a page.  I'd like the 5 to show up at a time, in a list, where the timing is such that every few seconds, the last div on the list is hidden, and another div from the list of 10 is shown.  Basically it would be cycling through the divs, constantly showing a list of 5, by hiding and showing certain divs.

Let's say that for this scrolling feed, @ticker_feed.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page =>10)

This would have 10 objects in it. Then I would want to output the entries, one div below the previous as such:

```
 <%@ticker_feed.each do |f|%>
<%= render 'discussions/ticker_tile' %>
<% end %>
```

BUT what I want is for the first 5 to show up, then the 1st to slide up (away) while the 6th rolls in, then 3,4,5,6,7, then 4,5,6,7,8... and so on. I think I would have to use jQuery. Assume that I can output a ticker_tile id of ticker_1, ticker_2, ticker_3 etc.. for the purpose of having selectors.

Anybody have some insight as to how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery plugin that scrolls items within a div, in the way you describe.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/autoscroll.html

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/PEwtJ/) shows one way to do it;  it's not quite what you wanted, I think.

---

The plugin is designed, it seems, to display ONE item at a time from the list.  When `circular = true` , allowing circular scrolling, the plugin clones the first and last item in the list of items that you want to scroll.  It then that one cloned item when reaching the end of the original list.

Understanding that, you can make a small change to jquery.tools.js to get the effect you want.  Rather than cloning one item, clone N items.  I added an option called `cloneCount` to take care of this problem.

Around line 2830:

```
            conf: {
                    maskId: 'exposeMask',

                    .... 

                cloneCount:1, // cheeso

                    // callbacks
                    onLoad: null,
                    onClose: null
            }
```

And then around line 261, where this is the original code:

```
            // circular loop
            if (conf.circular) {

                    var cloned1 = self.getItems().slice(-1).clone().prependTo(itemWrap),
                             cloned2 = self.getItems().eq(1).clone().appendTo(itemWrap);
```

...modify it to be like this:

```
            // circular loop
            if (conf.circular) {

                    var cloned1 = self.getItems().slice(-conf.cloneCount).clone().prependTo(itemWrap),
                             cloned2 = self.getItems().slice(conf.cloneCount).clone().appendTo(itemWrap);
```

finally, when you create the scroller, do this:

```
    var options = {
      circular: true,
      cloneCount:4,  // cheeso
      vertical: true,
      speed: 400
    };
    $("#scrollable-content").scrollable(options);
```

You will have to adjust the cloneCount number, depending on the height of the container, and the height of the items being scrolled within the container.

Here's [the updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/PEwtJ/1/).